# Why don't my thumbnails appear in the same row?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a basic image gallery using Bootstrap in AngularJS. I'm following a tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_thumbnails.htm but I've seen many other sites use the same or similar code.

When I run it on my page, instead of the 3 images appearing spaced out in the same row, they all appear centered on separate rows.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="" class="thumbnail">
            <img class="r" src="../Images/Test1.png" >
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="" class="thumbnail">
            <img class="" src="../Images/Test2.png" >
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="" class="thumbnail">
            <img class="" src="../Images/Test3.png" >
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code use **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** framework and you probably forget to import it !

Make sure you have these imports, and the code will work like you expect it :

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the prove that this html works fine once bootstrap imported :

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/10811/)**

Comment: Looks like it is an import issue. I originally had these imports:

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"> 


But I just commented them out and replaced them with yours. Unfortunately, it looks like the thumbnails are displaying correctly, but now my nav bar is displaying vertically and without the correct styling. I'll have to play with it and post back.

Comment: Looks like the nav bar tutorial I followed was way out dated since I was using 2.3. Found an updated version for 3.3.4 and it works fine.